# How To make the table for this fields

Tags: php, mysql

THis is my tutor segment form:
      Class I-V Tuition
        Class VI-VIII Tuition 
        Class IX-X Tuition
        Class XI-XII Tuition
        College Level
        Engineering Subjects

Based on my Tutor Selected Segment I am showing  different form. Assume user selects different classes, like class1-5 class6-8 class8-10 and engineering.How to make my table column please see example

```
 1.Tutor selected class I-V And class VI-VIII
    2.Tutor selected class I-V And class VI-VII AND Engineering

Here is my Db structure:
my column contains
tutorid  class1-5 class6-8 class 8-10 class10-12  collegelevel Engineering 

my question are:
1.user selected class1-5 and class6-8
INSERT INTO Tablename('class1-5,class6-8,class8-10,class10-12',collegelevel,engineering) values('class1-5','class6-8','remining column I don't have value');
2.user selected engineering
INSERT INTO Tablename('class1-5,class6-8,class8-10,class10-12',collegelevel,engineering) values('it has only engineering values' remaining column is null);
3.How to make the table for this. Here I have to keep my table column like this only.
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Normalize your database.

Your tutor table:

```
tutor_id
tutor_username
tutor_password <-- encrypt this
...
```

Your classes table:

```
class_id
class_name
```

Your users table:

```
user_id
user_username
user_password <--encrypt this
...
```

Your 'going to classes' (gtc) table:

```
gtc_id
gtc_user_id
gtc_class_id
```

So, when your user selects a class, it will create a new record in the `going to classes` table, so it might look like this:

```
| gtc_id | gtc_user_id | gtc_class_id |
|    0   |     16      |       1      |
|    1   |     16      |       2      |
|    2   |     17      |       1      |
```

and in your classes table:

```
| class_id | class_name
|    0     | English      
|    1     | Maths     
|    2     | Engineering
```

So, user 16 will go to classes `English` and `Engineering` while user 17 only goes to class `English`